# Problem in duplicating magento installation to subfolder

Tags: magento-1.9, migration

I am facing something like [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/61714/magento-multisite-testing-subfolders-resolving-to-live-subfolders) issue,
i cloned the live server to a sub-folder for testing purposes and created subdomain for it. Now
1- if i use subdomain.livesite.com as url (both secure/unsecure) all links (categories/products etc) on site target to livesite.com
and
2- if I use livesite.com/subfolder as base url, category urls works but product urls still target to livesite

**(links are not just redirected to live site, they actually had href attribute value of live site)**

Note: As the other question is not answered yet so i don't think of my question as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets begin with primary steps-
Have you cleared the cache after cloning ?
Is there any custom Base URL injected in your catalog while rendering ? (Maybe developer have made this static.)
Try to visit any product or category URL but typing the URL in browser, if page renders without redirection, then your URL must be static in menu, this could be due to megamenu or any menu module with custom HTML which may have static URL.

Comment: ** Is it on cloud ??? **

Comment: yes, cache cleared.
i was using ultimo fluid responsive theme with infortis megamenu, but for testing i disabled ultimo theme and all of its module, but still no luck

Comment: visiting product page by typing url in address bar only works if i use index.php in it,, without index.php it redirects to 404

Comment: Is it on cloud server ? Its definitely due to .htaccess

Comment: yes you were right, the issue was due to .htaccess, Thanx alot